# Fetching a specific SMS on Android

Tags: android, sms, broadcast

I am trying to do an app, that will discard SMS messages if it found any wanted header in it.

I have tried to look all over the web how to do it after the KitKat changes, and found out that I have to be a default app in order to get the SMS first.

After that done, I want to be able to pass the sms to all other apps that can listen to it(to be specific, using Galaxy I want the SMS to get to the Messages app).

No matter how much I tried I am not able to accomplish this.

Even if I don't issue "abortBroadcast()", the message is not passing to other apps.

I`ve tried to issue a broadcast message by myself in order to make the phone "belive" that it got an SMS. Again, no luck. (maybe I was doing it wrong)

Here is the code:

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

Object[] myPdusObj;
String minStr;
Intent myInt;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    myInt = intent;
    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            myPdusObj = pdusObj;
            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                if (parseMessage(message) == true) {
                    this.abortBroadcast();
                    // Save the message/other action
                }
                else {
                     // Do nothing, let the message pass to others
                }
            } 
        } 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}
```

And my manifest file(Was edited in order to appear as default sms app):

```
<application>
    <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming SMS messages -->
    <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
        >
        <intent-filter
            android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming MMS messages -->
    <receiver android:name=".IncomingMms"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
        <intent-filter
            android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter
            android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <!-- Service that delivers messages from the phone "quick response" -->
    <service android:name=".HeadlessSmsSendService"
        android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>



</manifest>
```

Hope it can be done and its just a small issue I am missing here...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to conclude, the possibility to prevent other applications from receiving the broadcast could be achieved either:

1. Being a system app - not possible for most developers
2. Ask the user to choose you as the default application, this way it is possible to prevent the broadcast from reaching other apps but demands your app to handle 'normal' messages(or just pass them on...)

Comment: "this way it is possible to prevent the broadcast from reaching other apps" - The `SMS_DELIVER` broadcast is sent to only the default SMS app. No other app will ever receive it, so the `abortBroadcast()` call is pointless. "but demands your app to handle 'normal' messages(or just pass them on...)" - The default SMS app is responsible for writing all incoming messages to the Provider. It cannot "pass them on". The `SMS_RECEIVED` action is still broadcast, and any app listening for it will get it, as it can no longer be aborted, but no app other than the default has write access to the Provider.

Answer (score 1):

"After that done, I want to be able to pass the sms to all other apps that can listen to it("

You've got to be a system app to do this. Have a look at the AOSP com/android/internal/telephony/InboundSmsHandler.java to see how Android is doing it.

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering,
I have reached a step where i get error saying "you have to be system app to do this", but got to dead-end realizing I can not be a system app.

Is there any way to by pass it, or another approach to my issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Not if you want to distribute your app on the Play Store.

Comment: I don't want it in play store, its for my usage only.
But from what I`ve seen I need a rooted device in order to make the app a system one, this is why I am trying to find another way to do it.

Comment: Oh well if it is just for yourself you should look at building the OS yourself. You can use the AOSP or Cyanogen if you want. AOSP is built using a default key which you can either use to sign your app, or you can include your source in the build. It' faster to just re-sign your app with the default key. Then you stick it in the /system directory on the phone and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answers David,
I was trying to find a workaround in order not to go through building my OS only for the sake of the SMS manipulations I want to achieve.. Hoping there was another solution to this.

Comment: If you don't want to go through the hassle of building AOSP, you could use download Cyanogen binaries instead and use their keys to sign your app as a system app.

Their keys are here: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_build/tree/gingerbread/target/product/security